# gruntjs tricky config

Tags: config, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I'm wondering how I can watch the files here :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    handlebars: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          "app/handlebars/handlebars-templates.js" : [
            "app/handlebars/*.handlebars"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      handlebars: {
        files: [
          '<%= handlebars.compile.files %>' <== what to put here ?
        ],
        tasks: 'default'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'handlebars');
};
```

I can put "app/handlebars/*.handlebars" but I want to write something which take the correct path dynamically

Comment: You might also want to look at [grunt-regarde](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-regarde). I think it does the job better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= handlebars.compile.files %>` in your config is pointing to an object. So the watch doesn't know which files you actually want. Try adding/reading a config var like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  handlebars_path: "app/handlebars/*.handlebars",
  handlebars: {
    compile: {
      files: {
        "app/handlebars/handlebars-templates.js" : [
          "<%= handlebars_path %>"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    handlebars: {
      files: [
        "<%= handlebars_path %>"
      ],
      tasks: 'default'
    }
  }
});
```

Or use a more explicit config:

```
handlebars: {
  compile: {
    src: ['app/handlebars/*.handlebars'],
    dest: 'app/handlebars/handlebars-templates.js'
  }
}
```

and get with `<%= handlebars.compile.src %>`.